CDKTF (Terraform) seems to execute JSON syntax instead of sending to AWS
System, packages and versions:

Terraform v1.5.7
CDKTF 0.20.8
NodeJS v18.20.4
Docker version 25.0.4, build 1a576c50a9
aws-cli/2.13.6 Python/3.11.4 Darwin/23.5.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off

 const iotTopicRule1 = new iotTopicRule.IotTopicRule(this, 'iot-topic-rule-1', {
    ...,
    errorAction: {
        s3: {
            "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:role/service-role/iot-write-to-failed-iot-s3-bucket",
            "bucketName" : "failed-iot-action-messages",
            "key" : "${replace(topic(), '/', '-') + '-' + timestamp() + '-' + newuuid()}",
        }
    }
})

When I run cdktf synth all things works correctly, but, when I run cdktf deploy <stack-name> the following error occur:
There is no function named "newuuid"
It's like terraform tries to run newuuid instead of sending that to AWS.
I expect the topic to be created in AWS as defined via typescript.

After trying several ways, I found the solution. The string defined in TypeScript must be escaped, otherwise Terraform sees the dollar sign as something to be executed locally.
So now it looks like this:
const iotTopicRule1 = new iotTopicRule.IotTopicRule(this, 'iot-topic-rule-1', {
    ...,
    errorAction: {
        s3: {
            "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:role/service-role/iot-write-to-failed-iot-s3-bucket",
            "bucketName" : "failed-iot-action-messages",
            "key" : "$${replace(topic(), '/', '-') + '-' + timestamp() + '-' + newuuid()}",
        }
    }
})

Now it's works correctly.

I was gonna give an answer but apparently you already gave the perfect answer! You should accept your own answer.
